# Axioms for vector space in Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right" - distributivity of scalar multiplication missing

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm self studying Linear Algebra with Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right (3rd edition). At page 12 the author introduces the following
 [axioms for a vector space.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L688H.png)

[image]

In other sources that I could find online, for example [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorSpace.html), the vecotor space axioms include also the associativity of scalar multiplication: $$For\ any\ scalar\ \alpha,\beta\ and \ any\ vector\ \mathbf v,\ \alpha(\beta\mathbf v) = (\alpha\beta)\mathbf v.$$

Is this an error in Axler book or the associativity for scalar multiplication can be derived in some way from the other properties?

Comment: Um, your first link, which presumably is the one you're complaining about by the text, includes associativity of scalar multiplication.

Comment: Sorry to everybody, I've made a mistake. In the book the associativity for scalar multiplication is written together with associativity for addition. I didn't noticed it beacuse I thought that the author was introducing first the properties for addition and then the properties for scalar multiplication, as it is normally done for example for field axioms.

Comment: If you feel that any of the answers below have successfully answered your question, you may accept one of them by clicking on the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: A vector space $V$ is defined as a space, or set, of vectors with satisfy some properties. For starters any pair of vectors can be added so that their sum remains in the space, and any vector can be scaled so that it stays in the space. To scale a vector we use scalars from a field $\mathbb F$. A field has axioms which can be shown separately. It looks like the author skipped the field stuff and tried to cram everything together to make a tidy definition of vector space.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's there. Unless I'm misunderstanding something, I think it is there. He grouped it with addition. Under "associativity".

---

Homedog, after your edit, it is still there. He simply is not explicitly saying
"Associativity of scalar multiplication" like your second source does.

Comment: I believe it's spelled "homedawg."